# Passing GDAL commands in Python using subprocess: errors

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, linux

Linux Ubuntu 22.04, latest GDAL installation (3.4.1).

**Note: skip to 'UPDATE' section further down in this question**

`gdalinfo` don’t recognise Ubuntu file paths or shapefiles:

```
gdalinfo “/home/username/docs/test.shp”
```

Leads to this error when run from the default terminal:

```
ERROR 4: /home/username/docs/test.shp: No such file or directory
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/home/username/docs/test.shp'.
```

Strangely a different error appears when Terminal is launched from the directory of the shapefile:

```
ERROR 4: `/home/username/docs/test.shp' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/home/username/docs/test.shp'.
```

Python has no issues recognising the folder paths. For example this returns all files in the folder:

```
import os
dir = r’/home/username/docs/‘
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    print(file)
```

returns:

```
test.shp
test.prj
test.dbf
test.shx
```

So it appears to be an issue with GDAL. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: as pointed out below, I need to use `ogrinfo` when working with vector data, not `gdalinfo` which is for raster data. However, I still have an issue referencing an absolute path to a shapefile, only when using gdal in Python (using `subprocess` `call` function). For example, using `ogr2ogr` in **Terminal**, this works:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /home/data/new.shp /home/data/old.shp
```

but in python this doesn't work:

```
from subprocess import call
command = r'ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /home/data/new.shp /home/data/old.shp'
call(command)
```

returns this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'oogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /home/data/new.shp /home/data/old.shp'
```

(I'm using dummy paths for this example)
From the error it looks like the entire gdal command is being used as a directory??

Comment: When you get the name/path problem resolved you may notice that gdalinfo is made for raster files. Use orginfo https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html for vector data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `call` method of `subprocess` doesn't work as well on Linux machines vs Windows. This script has worked for me before (on a Windows setup, with python 3.8):

```
from subprocess import call

command = r'ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:/data/new.shp C:/data/old.shp'
call(command)
```

I've now found that even when swapping the file paths for Linux friendly versions, `call` would treat the entire command as one long directory when I run this on an Ubuntu machine. My solution (from mightypile's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49986004)) is to use `subprocess.run` on a list instead:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", f"/home/data/new.shp", f"/home/data/old.shp"])
```

Notice how I didn't have to wrap `"ESRI Shapefile"` in additional single quotes. Also note the absolute paths.

In summary, I'm not sure if something has changed in the `subprocess` library since I last played with using python to pass gdal commands, or perhaps I had to try different approach on a Linux machine vs my previous Windows machines.

Comment: Look at `gdal.VectorTranslate`

Comment: @user2856 is that one of their python methods? Thanks

Comment: Yes - https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#:~:text=source%C2%A0code-,VectorTranslateOptions,-(options%3D

Answer (score 5):

If its a relative path, you need a period in front of the file path, such as

```
gdalinfo './Path/to/my/file.shp'
```

or for the whole path you would specify with tilde such as

```
gdalinfo '~/home//Path/to/my/file.shp'
```

so for you if its a relative path it should be

```
gdalinfo './home/username/docs/test.shp'
```

Your bigger problem is that [gdalinfo](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html) is for raster data

So you should actually be using [ogrinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html) instead, such as:

```
ogrinfo -so ./home/username/docs/test.shp
```

Comment: `/home/etc...` is an absolute path so the 1st part of your answer is not really relevant to the question, but you are correct about `gdalinfo` and `ogrinfo`

Comment: I prefer to work only with absolute paths (in case I move my script files around).
Thanks for reminding me about ogrinfo (it's been a while away from GDAL for me). Running terminal from the file directory, this works: `ogrinfo test.shp`, but I'm struggling to work out the correct syntax for absolute path...

Comment: @TheoF `ogrinfo /home/username/docs/test.shp`

Comment: @user2856 so I'm running a python script which calls `subprocess` to run the `ogr2ogr` command. The python script sits in `/home/username/github/repo/script.py` . The script references the shapefile in `/home/username/docs/test.shp'. I can't figure out how to reference this location as an absolute path in the python script. Even using your suggestion throws `FileNotFoundError...`